# Oracle SQL - Invalid Datatype when creating Table (No booleans)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table in my db, so I run this:

```
  CREATE TABLE SP
   (    
    SP_ID NUMBER(15,0) primary key, 
    SP_BEZ VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) not null, 
    SP ADD SP_BEZLANG varchar2(200),
    SP ADD SP_CODE varchar2(30),
    SP_ERTS TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP not null
   );
```

But it comes out as:

```
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I know that oracle does not support booleans, which is something I found out while googling for this problem, but this does not contain any, it's pretty short too.

Anyone see anything wrong with my create statement?
Thanks.

Database is Oracle 11g express edition.

Comment: No, no, this works (20 CHAR) lets the DBMS know that the field should be prepared with 20 characters (datatype) instead of 20 bytes as it does by default iirc.

Comment: you can tick as correct if you find solution below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### try this:

> 'SP ADD' is not working because 'ADD' is not datatype

```
CREATE TABLE SP
   (    
    SP_ID NUMBER(15,0) primary key, 
    SP_BEZ VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) not null, 
    SP_BEZLANG varchar2(200),
    SP_CODE varchar2(30),
    SP_ERTS TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP not null
   );
```

Comment: VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) is fine

Comment: I can't yet. "You can accept answer in 6 minutes" - I will after that ;)

Comment: I got it :) @Wep0n

Answer (score 1):

You have extra 'SP ADD', This's working:

```
CREATE TABLE SP
   (    
    SP_ID NUMBER(15,0) primary key, 
    SP_BEZ VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) not null, 
    SP_BEZLANG varchar2(200),
    SP_CODE varchar2(30),
    SP_ERTS TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP not null
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating table in oracle you can go through this documentation :

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN11004

In your case problem is you should create table in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE SP
 (  SP_ID NUMBER(15,0) primary key, 
    SP_BEZ VARCHAR2(20) not null, 
    SP_BEZLANG varchar2(200),
    SP_CODE varchar2(30),
    SP_ERTS TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP not null
   );
```